# How can Ruby functions with named arguments get called with a hash instead?

Tags: ruby, named-parameters, keyword-argument

I'm trying to get this foo function to output "first" and then "second" but instead it is outputting {:x=>"first", :y=>"second"} and "this is y".

How can I use the hash as named arguments?

```
def foo(x='hi', y='this is y')
  puts x
  puts y
end

hash = {x: 'first', y: 'second'}
foo(**hash)
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. There is no such thing as "named arguments" in Ruby. Are you talking about *keyword arguments*? But there are no keyword arguments in your code.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Can you take a look at meta:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385075/shall-we-synonymize-named-parameters-and-keyword-arguments ? I think your input would be valuable there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call the method with the hash: `foo(hash)`

The bigger problem: You didn't use named parameters (or better keyword arguments) but parameters with default values. To use named parameters you must not not use `=` but `:`.

```
def foo(x: 'hi', y:'this is y')
  puts x
  puts y
end

hash = {x: 'first', y: 'second'}
foo(hash)
```